# Issue centering components in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm coming from React Native so I'm still adjusting to ReactJS. I have two buttons, a regular one and an icon button. I want to center the regular button and have the iconbutton at the bottom of the screen. I've tried using justifyContents: 'center' and similar settings as shown in my code but it doesn't seem to work. All my code is below with comments showing where my button code is. Thank you for any assistance.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import SettingsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Settings';
import { Button , TextField, IconButton} from '@material-ui/core';

function App() {

  const [task, setTask] = useState("");
  const [goals, setGoal] = useState(["test"]);

  const addGoal = () => {
    setGoal([...goals, task]);
  };

  const listItems = goals.map((number) =>
    <li>{goals}</li>
  );

  return (
    <div style={{padding: 50, flexDirection: 'column'}}>

      <div style = {{display: 'flex', fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontSize: 55}}>
        <text>Tuesday</text>
      </div>

      <text style = {{display: 'flex', fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontSize: 45, marginBottom: 50}}>11:45</text>

      <div style = {{marginBottom: 20}}>
        <TextField inputProps={{style: {fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}} InputLabelProps = {{style: {fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}} id="standard-basic" autoComplete='off' label="New Goal"  fullWidth value = {task} onChange = {e => setTask(e.target.task)}/>
      </div>

      //TRYING TO CENTER THIS BUTTON
      <div style = {{display: 'flex', alignSelf: 'center', justifContent: 'center'}}>
        <Button variant="outlined" disableElevation size = "medium">
          Add Goal
        </Button>
      </div>

      <div style = {{flexDirection: 'column', paddingTop: 40}}>
        <ui>listItems</ui>
      </div>

      //TRYING TO HAVE THIS AT THE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE
      <div style = {{display: 'flex', justifContent: 'flex-end'}}>
        <IconButton>
          <SettingsIcon/>
        </IconButton>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Why not define a class for each element and style those elements on a different css page? Using so many inline css doesn't seem like the right method. I also think this is a question of CSS, not react js.

Comment: I've added a CSS tag as you've suggested, and I'm just using inline to get my head around the formatting style in ReactJS. I'd like to understand it in this form before separating it into classes.

Comment: I understand, but I suggest you don't make a habit of it. :) Good Luck!

Comment: For sure it's much less organized like this, just for learning purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, I think you missed it, but it should have been justifyContent, not justifContent.

```
  <div style = {{display: 'flex', alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>

  <div style = {{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
```

Comment: thanks so much sorry about that was a silly mistake

Comment: it's not a problem. It might have been overlooked. That's what this platform is for. If you had a separate css file instead of inline css, your error would be shown automatically. I want to say it. If you want to use css in the same page and you want to dynamically change the css you use with props, I can recommend styled-components. Will work for you. https://styled-components.com/

Comment: I'll look into this library. It seems to be a lot more organized than the method I'm using at the moment. Thank you for all the help I really appreciate it